# Djago error with PostgreSQL migration

Tags: django, postgresql, migration

I was trying to run my Django App with PostgreSQL as my database engine earlier used sqlite,
this is my settings.py. I was doing the installation by tutorial https://djangogirls.gitbooks.io/django-girls-tutorial-extensions/optional_postgresql_installation/

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'djangogirls',
        'USER': 'cherzik',
        'PASSWORD': 'ADMIN',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    }
}
```

this is errors, help please

```
d:\py\djangogirls>python manage.py migrate
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
blog.Comment.created_date: (fields.W161) Fixed default value provided.
        HINT: It seems you set a fixed date / time / datetime value as default f
or this field. This may not be what you want. If you want to have the current da
te as default, use `django.utils.timezone.now`
blog.Post.created_date: (fields.W161) Fixed default value provided.
        HINT: It seems you set a fixed date / time / datetime value as default f
or this field. This may not be what you want. If you want to have the current da
te as default, use `django.utils.timezone.now`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Кирюшик\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-package
s\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Кирюшик\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-package
s\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 189, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\Кирюшик\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-package
s\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 176, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\Кирюшик\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-package
s\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Кирюшик\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-package
s\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Кирюшик\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-package
s\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Кирюшик\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-package
s\django\core\management\base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Кирюшик\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-package
s\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Кирюшик\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-package
s\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 83, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "C:\Users\Кирюшик\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-package
s\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\Кирюшик\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-package
s\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\Кирюшик\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-package
s\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 209, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\Кирюшик\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-package
s\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 65, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "C:\Users\Кирюшик\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-package
s\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 52, in ensure_schema
    if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_name
s(self.connection.cursor()):
  File "C:\Users\Кирюшик\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-package
s\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 254, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\Кирюшик\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-package
s\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 229, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Кирюшик\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-package
s\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Кирюшик\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-package
s\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\Кирюшик\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-package
s\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Кирюшик\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-package
s\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Кирюшик\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-package
s\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 189, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\Кирюшик\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-package
s\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 176, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\Кирюшик\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-package
s\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError
```

Comment: Post your models please.

Comment: It seems that your code can't connect to PostgreSQL. Check that you have PostgreSQL installed and running, and that name of the postgresql database, user and password are correctly set in Django settings.

Answer (score 0):

this is my model and if i replace created_date to timezone.now like you said anyway has an error

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
# Create your models here.

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank = True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def approved_comments(self):
        return self.comments.filter(approved_comment = True)

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', related_name='comments')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = timezone.now()
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the created_date field like this,

```
created_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
```

Or

```
created_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
```

Remove the paranthesis of the function.
With the paranthesis, the function will only be called when models.py loads.
If we remove the paranthesis, we are passing a callable to the model and it will be called each time a new instance is saved.

Answer (score 0):

change your created_date field in both Comment and Post model.

```
created_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
```